# JavaScript - Keep pseudo classes (:hover, :active, :focus) active, until released

Tags: javascript, css, class, triggers, release

How would I be able to keep these states (:hover, :focus, :active, etc) active, until released?

**Take a look at this example:**

```
<style> div:hover, div:focus, div:active { background: red; } </style>

<div tabindex="-1">I would be red, if hovered, focused or being active. Until the button 'toggle off' is pressed.</div>

<button onclick="toggleItem('on', 'hover');">Toggle on</button>
<button onclick="toggleItem('off', 'hover');">Toggle off</button>

function toggleItem(action, style)
{
    if (action == "on")
    {
        // style activation
    }
    else if (action == "off")
    {
        // disable activated style
    }
}
```

I was thinking of setting an interval, which will trigger this state every x seconds. But doesn't seem to be "good practice"... Any suggestions?

**Basically just like the developer tools:**

[image]

Comment: That’s not really possible. Your best bet is to use class names corresponding to the respective state (`div:hover, div.hover, …`), and toggle those.

Comment: @CBroe I've updated my question, with an image. How do they support this feature?

Comment: Dev tools/browser extensions get access to lower-level APIs etc., that you don’t have access to from within the scope of a regular website.

Comment: @CBroe That's true. But there must be a way in order to achieve my fulfilling. That's the cool part about programming.. nothing is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you especially need those states ?

You could just add classes to your div : .div_hover, .div_focus{ your style }
And add/remove those classes in your JS script.

Comment: This is an experiment for a project of mine. Using classes is not an option in this case :/